# Passing advice to mode line

Tags: mode-line, advice

I'd like to advise `format-mode-line` to collapse whitespace across the whole string. The following attempt does not work for me.

`(advice-add 'format-mode-line :filter-return 'collapse-whitespace)`

When I evaluate `(format-mode-line mode-line-format)`, the output seems to be what I want, but the appearance of my mode line does not change.

Comment: Very strange behavior, I find that if I advise the function in other ways, such as adding a character to the end it works as expected but collapsing whitespace does not. What does work for me, if you're seeking another working solution, is to change your mode-line-format to something like this: `'((:eval (collapse-whitespace (format-mode-line original-mode-line-format))))`